# Is it a good practice to have a separate, servlet independent "server logic" running on a dynamic web project for Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

sorry in advance for the stupid question - the question is probably obvious too many.

I'm currently working on a Java EE 7 tutorial and have built my first applications with Servlets, JSP and JSF, deployed on a Payara application server.

Even though the book covers many topics, I don't understand one basic thing: Is it good practice and even possible to have a independent server functionality running on my application next to the JSF's that handle client connections? Maybe even standalone without any web application functionalities?

Similar to a Javascript SPA + PHP Backend. Only that I'd have everything in one application and wouldn't need to a websocket or similar between my client and server.

I've been searching a lot on Google and I guess that my main problem is, that I don't get the basic understanding. On everything I've seen, JEE applications start with a HTTP communication to the web container.

I'd like to have an independent server that is communicating with the client sessions. It's not even completely clear to me, where that server application would be supposed to be running as both the web container and the ejb container don't seem applicable to me (especially, I don't need EJB functionalities)

It would be great if anything give me a few hints on this topic. I don't need a tutorial, but something like "you should use @ApplicationScoped beans as the entry point to start up the server", "you're doing it completely wrong, JEE is not meant for an architecture like this" or similar to get me thinking into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

java ee and its component (excluding ejb in case of remote ejbs), run in one server. a container in javaee is a logical management unit. it understands how to manage different components. e.g. ejb container understands how to manage ejb beans, how to initiate them and manage their lifecycle. cdi container understands how to manage cdi bean lifecycle. jsf components run within the servlet container.

with the current javaee architecture specification, those containers have a well defined "link" on how to interact. e.g. a no inteeface stateless bean will automatically be registered with the cdi container using the ejb lookup convention proxied and injected using normal cdi injection mechanism.

on jsf specification interaction with cdi beans has been defined through the @Named annotation which instructs cdi to avail the so annotated bean for lookup using el expression.

so depending on how you structure your application, and using jsf as your frontend, only ejb container can run on a different server with remote interfaces. cdi and jsf will run in the same server and the need for websocket is only if you need such a functionality.

note that jsf is component based and is wholly rendered at the server, no websocket, no additional http connections. so you only need a single server and the browser as your client

as for things like "@ApplicationScoped" beans, these annotations instructs the cdi container simply on how to manage the lifecycle of the so annotated bean. in this case, as long as the application is running, the bean will be in memory for injection.